# Find the area described by $S=\{(x,y)\mid -2<x\leq 0, 0\leq y\leq 2/\sqrt{x+2}\}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Find the area described by $S=\{(x,y)\mid -2<x\leq 0, 0\leq y\leq 2/\sqrt{x+2}\}$.

I have tried to use logic to figure out what to do but cannot figure it out. I have tried to think about this region as a set of values that satisfy the conditions but then I have no idea how to integrate it if that is the case. Thank you.

Comment: Note that $S$ is the set of points under the graph $y=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+2}}$ with $-2 < x \leq 0$.

Comment: Okay if I integrate 2/(sqrt(x+2)), I get 4(sqrt(x+2)) and when I evaluate this integral from -2(exclusively) to 0, I end up with (4(2)^(1/2))-4(1/(sqrt(x+2)) and taking the limit as x-> -2 from the right gives -inf but it says this is wrong.

Comment: okay never mind guys I got it.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-2}^0 \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x+2}} dx =4\sqrt{x+2}\quad|_{-2}^0=4\sqrt{2}$